# How do I replace \n with <br> in dart?

Tags: html, dart

This will not work

```
    String t = "Lorem\nipsum";
    Element br = new Element.tag('br');
    t = t.replaceAll('\n', br);
```

And neither will

```
    String t = "Lorem\nipsum";
    String br = "<br>";
    t = t.replaceAll('\n', br);
```

Of course, if there are some safe way for Dart to handle HTML inputs on the frontend, then that would be the optimal solution. But the closest I've found is templates which afaik only runs backend (?).

For now, just replacing \n's with <br>'s would be just fine but it has to be done from frontend since what I'm building doesn't have a backend (only using localStorage for now).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works:

```
String t = "Lorem\nipsum";
String br = "<br>";
t = t.replaceAll('\n', br);
query("#text").innerHTML = t;
```

(If you are satisfied with this answer, don't be afraid to click the checkmark. My boss promised to buy me lunch if I got 2 questions answered by tomorrow!)

Comment: It did indeed! Thank you, and enjoy your lunch :)